# Devise User ID skips several numbers in auto increment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, devise

I have section of code that programmatically creates a new devise user:

```
    user = User.new
    user.username = params[:username]
    user.email = params[:email]
    user.password = params[:password]

    if user.save
        render :json => user
    else
        render :json => user.errors
    end
```

I have recently noticed that the `user id` has skipped about 30 numbers in my records.

Looking at my records I have:

[image]

Any idea what might have caused this huge gap in the increment? Users have no way to delete their account.

Comment: What do you get when running `User.count`? Also, what DB are you using? Have you enabled transactions on the `users` table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're deployed on Heroku, you're using Postgres. In Postgres, primary keys ids are allocated just once in an linear, autoincremented sequence. But in the event that a transaction is rolled back, the allocated id will *still* be marked as used and will *not* be allocated again.

It's impossible to tell definitively, but my guess is that the creation of all users between `30` and `61` were rolled back due to some transactional error. You may want to crosscheck against your repository commits to see whether you made any modifications to your `User` model that might correspond to the time frame during which no users were committed to the DB.

Basically, things were working at one point, then they broke, and now they're working again. Check the period between `User.find(29).created_at` and `User.find(62).created_at` and see whether any commits may have impacted your model.

Comment: And I'll see you in the MUSS!

Comment: Hmm thats what I guessed might've been happening. Its not a huge deal because the app still works fine, just wanted to know the cause!